# Identical query definition but with different response in graphql

Tags: graphql, apollo

I am using react and apollo

I made a query in a file that looks like

query1.graphql

```
query User($pk: Int!) {
    user(pk: $pk) {
        id
        email
        name
        userType
        ...
    }
}
```

Now, in another place in the code I would like to request only one field.

query2.graphql

```
query User($pk: Int!) {
    user(pk: $pk) {
        id
    }
}
```

but this during generation will trigger an error that the query is already defined, but I don't want to have all the parameters

Is there a way to do so ? Or I just have to use the big query and keep what I want ?

Comment: Try this, https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/v2/data/fragments/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear what you're referring to by "generation" or what exact error you're seeing. However, assuming you're using GraphQL Code Generation, each operation must have a unique name, so you cannot have two operations with the same name (`User`). Change one of the operation names to something else.